# Quickly build large dict in elegant manner

Tags: python

I have a list with size about 30000: `['aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd', ...]`, from this list, I want to build a dict which maps element to index, so the result dict is `{'aa': 0, 'bb': 1, 'cc': 2, 'dd': 3, ...}`. Here comes my code:

```
cnt = 0
mp = {}
for name in name_list:
    mp[name] = cnt
    cnt += 1
return mp
```

It seems my code is not concise and effective, so how to improve it?

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You should question whether you really want to create such a large dictionary (or list for that matter).  Python has very powerful methods for iterating through large data sets without storing them in memory.

Comment: Why your value with `'dd'` key is `1`?

Comment: Why is `bb` mapped to 2?

Comment: sorry about mistakes, corrected already

Comment: @ChrisMueller this dictionary will be passed to js

Answer (score 5):

The shortest is to use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) and a dict comprehension, I guess:

```
mp = {element: index for index, element in enumerate(name_list)}
```

Comment: In my test, this code returns wrong map:{'aa': 0, 'cc': 2, 'dd': 3, 'bb': 1}

Comment: cc should map to 3

Comment: @vinllen: in your test data, 'cc' is the third element (so index 2) and 'dd' is the third (so index 3). Others have already commented on your question that your data or result seem to be wrong.

Comment: sorry about make a mistake

Comment: @vinllen you need to look carefully at the output from your own code. If you print the whole dictionary, the [order of the elements is not fixed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15479928/why-is-the-order-in-dictionaries-and-sets-arbitrary). This code neatly matches your own.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) to create the mapping between list object and the indices, then call `dict` on the reversed outputs:

```
mp = dict(tup[::-1] for tup in enumerate(name_list))
```

Answer (score 1):

How about using the list index for each item?

```
mp = {item: name_list.index(item) for item in name_list}
```

Comment: That's completely inefficient.

Comment: `.index()` has to loop through the entire list until it finds the item. This way it has to do that for each item, so it'll be very very slow with 30k items. Worse, if an item occurs twice in the list, this will give the same index twice, so it'll be wrong as well.